Find a hyphen and a numeric value of a string and write to a new column
I have a SQL table with Address column with string values, for example "Synnot Road, Balwyn Victoria 3074, Australia - 220".
In this string, I want to check whether the hyphen and the numeric value comes after the word ‘Australia’ exists. and if so, write the number after the word ‘Victoria’ into a new column. In this example the hyphen and the numeric value is - 220. The number after the word ‘Victoria’ is 3074 so the new column value should be 3074.
I tried this code below, but it writes the number as -220 in the new column (MyNewColumn) instead of the value 3074.
case when RIGHT([Address], CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE([Address]))) = 0  then RIGHT(replace([Address], ', Australia', ''), 4) 
else RIGHT(replace([Address], ', Australia', ''), 4) 
end as MyNewColumn

Appreciate for any help to correct the code.


what is your dbms? 2. show your code pls


which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

This is going to be hard to swing in SQL Server.  I suggest doing this transformation in your source CSV data outside of SQL Server.  Use something like Notepad++ with regex capabilites, then reimport the data.

The SQL in your question contains built-in functions, including CHARINDEX, which is not part of standard SQL and several DBMS's contain such a function, including SQL Server, Informix and SAP. Hence I think you need to [edit] your question and indicate which DBMS you are using.

In BigQuery, this works:
WITH addresstable AS (
  SELECT 
    "Synnot Road, Balwyn Victoria 3074, Australia - 220" AS address
)

SELECT 
  address,
  CASE
    WHEN 
      REGEXP_CONTAINS(address, r"Australia - \d+") -- must contain 1 or more digits after "Australia - "
      AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(address, r"Victoria \d{4}") -- must contain 4 digits after "Victoria "
        THEN 
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_EXTRACT(address,r"Victoria \d{4}"), r"\d{4}") --create a subset of "Victoria [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" and then extract the 4 digits
  END AS postcode
FROM
  addresstable

In TSQL / MS SQL Server, this works:
WITH addresstable AS (
  SELECT 
    "Synnot Road, Balwyn Victoria 3074, Australia - 220" AS address
)

SELECT 
  address,
  CASE
    WHEN 
      address LIKE "%Australia - [0-9][0-9][0-9]%" -- must contain 3 digits after "Australia - "
      AND address LIKE "%Victoria [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%" -- must contain 4 digits after "Victoria "
        THEN 
          SUBSTRING(address,CHARINDEX("Victoria ",address)+9,4) --get index position of "Victoria " from address, add 9 to it, and take the next 4 characters
  END AS postcode
FROM
  addresstable

Note that SQL Server is not as flexible with regexes as BigQuery when using LIKE.

Thank you so much!!. This part of the code helped me to capture the postcode ,case when [Location] LIKE '%Victoria [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING([Location],CHARINDEX('Victoria ',[Location])+9,4) else -1 end as Postcode
